# Помогите создать резинувую верстку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите создать резиновую верстку с этого кода
main.html
main.css

```js
function redirect() {
  var username = document.getElementById("login").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "") {
    alert("Enter your login, please");
  } else if (password == "") {
    alert("Enter your password, please");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "mysite.url/" + username + "/" + password;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #34495e;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #191919;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" id="login">
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" onclick="redirect()">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function redirect() {
  var username = document.getElementById("login").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == "") {
    alert("Enter your login, please");
  } else if (password == "") {
    alert("Enter your password, please");
  } else {
    window.location.href = "mysite.url/" + username + "/" + password;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #34495e;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #191919;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="text"],
.box input[type="password"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="text"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
}

@media(max-width: 380px) {
  .box {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .box input[type="text"],
  .box input[type="password"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .box input[type="text"]:focus,
  .box input[type="password"]:focus {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 190px) {
  .box input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 14px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username" id="login">
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Log in" onclick="redirect()">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, что сделали. Хотя какой вопрос, такой и ответ).

Comment: @OliverPatterson, да я думал видно, что добавлены медиа запросы